# How to save space by taking 3 lines and turning it into 1 string

Tags: python, modular

I’m trying to save space by taking 3 lines into 1 string. Can anyone help me out I’ve tried this but it’s not working.

```
sentence = sentence.replace ("(", "" + ")","")
```

​

```
def main():
    sentence = input("Enter a 10 digit telephonenumber in the format (XXX)XXX-XXXX: ")
    sentence = sentence.replace ("(", "")
    sentence = sentence.replace (")", "")
    sentence = sentence.replace ("-", "")
    print(sentence)

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either do it in a loop on one line. I'd recommend do in a loop if you have a lot of replacements, as it makes it easy to add more, but if it's just a small amount, then one line is fine.

Loop:

```
def main():
    sentence = input("Enter a 10 digit telephonenumber in the format (XXX)XXX-XXXX: ")
    remove_chars = list("()-")
    for char in remove_chars:
        sentence = sentence.replace(char, "")
    print(sentence)
```

Single line:

```
def main():
    sentence = input("Enter a 10 digit telephonenumber in the format (XXX)XXX-XXXX: ")
    sentence = sentence.replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace("-", "")
    print(sentence)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line like this:

```
sentence = sentence.replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace("-", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

Chaining so many `replace()` is rather ugly. You can use regular expressions

```
import re;
sentence = input("Enter a 10 digit telephonenumber in the format (XXX)XXX-XXXX: ")
sentence = re.sub('[-\(\)]', '', sentence)
```

You can also use `translate()`

```
sentence.translate({ord(i):None for i in '()-'})
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the replace method returns a string you can simple do another
replace on the returned string.  Something like sentence.replace().replace().replace():

```
sentence = sentence.replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace("-", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

A fast way to strip unwanted characters from a string is with `str.translate`:

```
>>> '(123)456-7890'.translate(None, '()-')
'1234567890'
```

Python 3 interface:

```
>>> '(123)456-7890'.translate(dict.fromkeys(ord(c) for c in '()-'))
'1234567890'
```

Answer (score 1):

`sentence = ''.join([c for c in sentence if c not in '(-)'])`

I prefer this to `replace` chaining because it's easier to expand to longer lists of characters.